# Error: Not allowed by CORS issue inside of Express app

Tags: node.js, express, server, cors

I make a request to any of our CRUD routes and I get this error. I am not familiar with server side code enough to give better details for the question. I am running this all inside of Docker by the way.

```
const clientHost = `http://${process.env.CLIENT_HOST}`;

const whitelist = [clientHost];

const corsOptions = {
  origin(origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      console.log(origin);
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  }
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

**RECEIVED ERROR:**

```
Error: Not allowed by CORS
at origin (/backend/server.js:24:16)
 at /backend/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
 at optionsCallback (/backend/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
  at corsMiddleware (/backend/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
 at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
 at trim_prefix (/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
 at /backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
 at expressInit (/backend/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

export CLIENT_HOST= Whatever your console.log(origin) printed to terminal right before your Error: Not allowed by CORS error (without the http://)

stop your node process completely and start it again in the same terminal window you exported the CLIENT_HOST variable in.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to allow only specific IPs to access your system, the Whitelisted IPs come from process.env.CLIENT_HOST, you need to add the IP address from the origin and add it in process.env.CLIENT_HOST.